# SQL query from a View

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, view

So i have two database tables called "video" and "related". The table "video" has 3 columns: id, views and category. The table "related" has 2 columns: a (same as the column id of the table "video") and b (id of the related video to a).

Here is an example of table "video":

**ID** | **views** | **category**

1 | 11000 | music

2 | 13000 | art

3 | 14000 | music

4 | 60000 | music

5 | 80000 | art

......

An example of table "related"

**a** | **b**

1 | 2

1 | 3

2 | 1

2 | 4

2 | 5

......

As you can see the id of the related video can be found on the table "video" as well.

So now I have this View:

- Views>=10000  ====> Category = 'Music'

And I need to convert it into an SQL query. I need to state the following: from all the video IDs with views above 10000 which ones of their related videos have category = "music".

I hope you don't find it as confusing as it seems...Thank you for your time and i am waiting for any possible help...

Comment: I suppose you mean *directly* related, yes? Or is 1 related to 4, because 1 is related to 2 which is related to 4.

Comment: It might be good to show your expected results.

Comment: Yes i mean directly related.think of youtube. there is a video and then a couple other videos related to that one. The end result should have a list of all the related videos (b column) with category "music" which are related to the videos with more than 10000 views.  it is a bit confusing! if you take a look at the View i provided it will become clearer! :D

Answer (score 1):

```
select * 
from video v1 
where v1.id in (
   select r.a 
   from related r 
   join video v2 on r.b = v2.id 
   where v2.category = 'music' )
and v1.views >= 10000
```

**Edit**

In your comment below, you asked for something completely different from the original question - namely, you NOW want videos in category "music" where the related video has more than 10000 views.  The SQL for your NEW question is this.

```
select * 
from video v1 
where v1.id in (
   select r.a 
   from related r 
   join video v2 on r.b = v2.id 
   where v2.views > 10000 )
and v1.category = 'music'
```

but please, next time you want to ask a different question from the original, just make a new question.

Comment: This statement does not give the desired result. It also show videos which are not in category "music" but they do have more than 10000 views. the end result should show only videos in category music (and no other category) which are related to the videos that have more than 10000 views. But i think you are close to what i am looking for!! :D thanks for the immediate response by the way!

Comment: You said _from all the video IDs with views above 10000 which ones of their related videos have category = "music"_ - and that's exactly what I gave you.  I have now added an answer to your new question.